# Proving $a^2 +b^2$ has constant value for all values of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The question says that **Angle x is such that $\sin x= a + b$ and $\cos x= a - b$, where a and b are constants. Show that $a^2 + b^2$ has a constant value for all values of $x$.**

I tried out solving it by algebra identities, but I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Learning basic $\LaTeX$ might be helpful. You do so by writing dollar signs, and "code" between them. For example, `$\sin x$` would produce $\sin x$, instead of sin x or $sin x$

Comment: Ahh sure ill use them the next time. Im quite new here so yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$sin(x) = a + b, cos(x) = a - b$$

$$sin^2(x) + cos^2(x) = (a + b) ^ 2 + (a - b) ^ 2 = 1$$

$$a^2+2ab+b^2+a^2-2ab+b^2=1$$

$$2a^2+2b^2=1$$

$$a^2+b^2=\frac{1}{2}$$

Therefore, $a^2+b^2$ has a constant value - in particular, $\frac{1}{2}$.

Cheers! :)

Comment: The identity $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ is true for all $x$ - even for complex numbers, if you're interested! Have fun with trigonometry and math, and welcome to stackexchange.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have that $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab=(a-b)^2+2ab.$ This gives $(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2=4ab,$ from where you get $2ab.$ Then substitute in either of the above identities to get $$\sin^2x-\frac12(\sin^2x-\cos^2x)=\frac12\sin^2x+\frac12\cos^2x=\frac12.$$

Comment: You also have sin^2+cos^2=1, and this a and b are not any numbers.

Comment: @GarethMa I'd made a mistake in my earlier calculation. Now repaired.